# Product page Image Gallery Loading Issue

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, products, magento-product-attributes

I'm getting images of product and using custom slider to load the product images in product details page,

The product is loading normally but sometimes when we refresh the page, Images wont showup. In HTML image URLs will be there, but it wont show up in the frontend. In console I'm getting only below error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
at jquery.mobile.custom.js:44
at jquery.mobile.custom.js:523
at jquery.mobile.custom.js:15
at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
at Module.check (require.js:866)
at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1113)
at require.js:132
at require.js:1156
at each (require.js:57)
at Module.emit (require.js:1155)
```

since this error is related to jquery mobile and showing in every page, I assume this is not the cause.
The issue is is arising sometimes, not every time. once i refresh the page images are loading properly.

Tried fushing chache, clear browser cache, etc.. nothing helped.

You can check the error in below website

**https://mytraveller.shop**

Since there are no error from JS end, I'm undable to figure out the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: you check the system.log ??

Comment: please refer this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497347/jquery-mobile-1-4-5-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-concat-of-undefin